# C# interactive でRailsのreload!のようにプロジェクト内のクラスを読み込む方法はありますか？

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2015 Community をの C# interactive でコンソールのプログラムを作り始めたのですが、プロジェクト内で定義されたクラスや関数を読み込む方法はありますか？

とりあえず今はクラスのコードをコンソールに直接貼り付けて動作を確認してるのですが。
Railsでいうと`reload!`のような機能を探しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#load`コマンドで拡張子csxのC#スクリプトを読み込めるみたいですよ。

[csi.exeコマンド登場！ C#スクリプト（.csx）やREPLを動かそう](http://www.buildinsider.net/language/csharpscript/01)

Comment: `.csx`を読み込む時は`#load`で生成したDLLを読み込む時は`#r`を使うみたいですね。ありがとうございます。